# Assign a variable to a value stored in a file

Tags: java

Let's say I setting.txt file somewhere in my file system (/home/settings for example). In that settings file I have several values set as so:

```
x file location = /tmp
logging level = INFO
mongo.host=ale.google.com
metrics account number = 14
```

In my class, I want to set an account number equal to the metrics account number in that file. How would I do that? I looked for an answer but all I could find was information about classpath variables.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write code to read `setting.txt` then navigate to `metrics account number` line and read the value.

Comment: You'll need to parse the text file into some kind of custom data structure.